# Purcell Effect Without RWA

Tags: quantum-mechanics, simulations

I am trying to simulate a coupled qubit-resonator system, and want to extract the [Purcell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purcell_effect) decay rate of the qubit. For that, I initialise the qubit in state $\left|1\right>$ and fit the probability of being in state $\left|1\right>$ as function of time.

I am doing the simulation with and without the [Rotating Wave Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating-wave_approximation) (RWA).

If I apply the RWA,the qubit decays to the ground state of the system, which is close to the bare $\left|0, 0\right>$ state, and the Purcell rate is given by the formula: $$\Gamma_P=\kappa\frac{g^2}{(\kappa/2)^2+\Delta^2} \ ,$$ with $\kappa$ the dissipation rate, $g$ the coupling term and $\Delta$ the qubit-cavity detuning.

[image: Evolution with RWA]

However, without RWA, the qubit does not decay towards $\left|0, 0\right>$, and I have a non-zero (and not small) probability to be in the end in the initial state.

[image: Evolution without RWA]

I tried to play with the dimensions of the Hilbert space, but it does not affect the finite value, neither do $\kappa$ nor $g$. However, when I reduce $\Delta$, the final value seems to decrease, which is very counterintuitive for me. Do you understand what is happening? Is there a physical reason for this or am I doing something wrong?

Here is my `qutip`code:

```
from qutip import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
%matplotlib widget



# qubit x resonator
nQubit, nRes = 4,4


a  = tensor(qeye(nQubit), destroy(nRes))
sm = tensor(destroy(nQubit), qeye(nRes))

g = 0.111

EQ = 0.9
EC = 2.085

cavity_kappa = 40e-3

use_rwa = False
if use_rwa :
    H = 2 * np.pi * EC * a.dag() * a + 2 * np.pi * EQ * sm.dag() * sm + g * (sm*a.dag()+sm.dag()*a)
else :
    H = 2 * np.pi * EC * a.dag() * a + 2 * np.pi * EQ * sm.dag() * sm + g * (sm+sm.dag())*(a+a.dag())

c_ops = [np.sqrt(2*np.pi*cavity_kappa)*a]
tlist = np.linspace(0, 5*10**4, 5*10**4+1)

rhoss = steadystate(H,c_ops)
print(np.real(np.diag(rhoss)))
psi0 = H.eigenstates()[2][2]
result = mesolve(H, psi0, tlist, c_ops, [psi0.proj()])

fig, axs = plt.subplots()
axs.plot(tlist,result.expect[0],label='simu',marker='x')

def model(t,gamma,p0) :
    return (1-p0)*np.exp(-gamma*t)+p0
Delta = EQ-EC
Gamma = cavity_kappa*(g/(2*np.pi))**2/((cavity_kappa/2)**2+Delta**2)*2*np.pi

popt, _ = curve_fit(model,tlist,result.expect[0])
axs.plot(tlist,model(tlist,*popt),color='k',linestyle='dashed',label='fit')
axs.plot(tlist,np.exp(-Gamma*tlist),label='th')
axs.set_xlabel("t (ns)")
axs.set_ylabel("probability")
axs.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
if use_rwa :
    axs.set_title('With RWA')
else :
    axs.set_title('Without RWA')
plt.tight_layout()
print(popt[0],Gamma)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I think I found the answer.

First, the Lindblad master equation assume a coupling to the bath including the negative frequencies. This is an issue outside RWA because the term $a^\dagger\sigma_+$ rotates at frequency $-\Sigma$ with $\Sigma$ the sum frequency.
Instead, one can use the Bloch-Redfield equation with [`brmesolve`](https://qutip.org/docs/latest/modules/qutip/bloch_redfield.html#brmesolve) assuming a coupling to the bath $\kappa(a+a^\dagger)$ only for **positive** frequencies.

If one does this, one get a probability that goes to zero, but with the incorrect decay rate. Finally, one has to change the formula form $\Gamma_P$ to take into account the correction from $\Sigma$ (which in my case was not much bigger than $\Delta$):

$\Gamma_P^{\rm NO~RWA} = \kappa\left(\frac{g}{\sqrt{(\kappa/2)^2+\Delta^2}}+\frac{g}{\sqrt{(\kappa/2)^2+\Sigma^2}}\right)^2$

[image: Corrected Decay Without RWA]

Here is my code:

```
from qutip import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
%matplotlib widget



# qubit x resonator
nQubit, nRes = 2,2


a  = tensor(qeye(nQubit), destroy(nRes))
sm = tensor(destroy(nQubit), qeye(nRes))

g = 0.111

EQ = 0.9
EC = 2.085

cavity_kappa = 40e-3

use_rwa = False
if use_rwa :
    H = 2 * np.pi * EC * a.dag() * a + 2 * np.pi * EQ * sm.dag() * sm + g * (sm*a.dag()+sm.dag()*a)
else :
    H = 2 * np.pi * EC * a.dag() * a + 2 * np.pi * EQ * sm.dag() * sm + g * (sm+sm.dag())*(a+a.dag())

tlist = np.linspace(0, 5*10**4, 5*10**4+1)

c_ops = [np.sqrt(2*np.pi*cavity_kappa)*a]

rhoss = steadystate(H,c_ops)
print(np.real(np.diag(rhoss)))
psi0 = H.eigenstates()[1][1]


#result = mesolve(H, psi0, tlist, c_ops, [psi0.proj()])
result = brmesolve(H, psi0, tlist, [[(a + a.dag()),lambda w : 2*np.pi*cavity_kappa*(w > 0)]], e_ops=[psi0.proj()])

fig, axs = plt.subplots()
axs.plot(tlist,result.expect[0],label='simu',marker='x')

def model(t,gamma,p0) :
    return (1-p0)*np.exp(-gamma*t)+p0
Delta = EQ-EC
Sigma = EQ+EC
if use_rwa :
    Gamma = cavity_kappa*(g/(2*np.pi))**2*(1/np.sqrt((cavity_kappa/2)**2+Delta**2))**2*2*np.pi
else :
    Gamma = cavity_kappa*(g/(2*np.pi))**2*(1/np.sqrt((cavity_kappa/2)**2+Delta**2)+1/np.sqrt((cavity_kappa/2)**2+Sigma**2))**2*2*np.pi

popt, _ = curve_fit(model,tlist,result.expect[0])
axs.plot(tlist,model(tlist,*popt),color='k',linestyle='dashed',label='fit')
axs.plot(tlist,np.exp(-Gamma*tlist),label='th')
axs.set_xlabel("t (ns)")
axs.set_ylabel("probability")
axs.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
if use_rwa :
    axs.set_title('With RWA')
else :
    axs.set_title('Without RWA')
plt.tight_layout()
print(popt[0],Gamma)
```